# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the error below:

> Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

I am trying to get routes from google map using places API using the following code.

```
private void getDirection() {
    currentPosition = new LatLng(Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude(),Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude());

    String requestApi = null;
    try{
        requestApi = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+
                "mode=driving&"+
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+
                "origin="+currentPosition.latitude+","+currentPosition.longitude+"&"+
                "destination="+destination+"&"+
                "key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);
        Log.d("HAMZA",requestApi); //Print URL for debugging purpose.
        mService.getPath(requestApi)
                .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                            for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject route = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                JSONObject poly = route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                String polyline = poly.getString("points");
                                polyLineList = decodePoly(polyline);
                            }
                            //Adjusting bounds
                            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                            for (LatLng latLng:polyLineList)
                                builder.include(latLng);
                            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                            CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,2);
                            mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);

                            polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                            polylineOptions.width(5);
                            polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            polylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                            greyPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                            blackPolylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                            blackPolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                            blackPolylineOptions.width(5);
                            blackPolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                            blackPolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                            blackPolyline = mMap.addPolyline(blackPolylineOptions);

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size()-1))
                                    .title("Pickup Location"));

                            //Animation
                            ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
                            polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                            polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                            polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                    List<LatLng> points = greyPolyline.getPoints();
                                    int percentValue = (int)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                    int size = points.size();
                                    int newPoints = (int)(size * percentValue/100.0f);
                                    List<LatLng> p = points.subList(0,newPoints);
                                    blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                                }
                            });
                            polyLineAnimator.start();

                            carMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition)
                            .flat(true)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));

                            handler = new Handler();
                            index=-1;
                            next=1;
                            handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable,3000);


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(Welcome.this,""+t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and using this parser from jeffreysambells

```
public class DirectionJSONParser {
/** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

    List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>();
    JSONArray jRoutes = null;
    JSONArray jLegs = null;
    JSONArray jSteps = null;

    try {

        jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

        /** Traversing all routes */
        for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
            jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
            List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            /** Traversing all legs */
            for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                /** Traversing all steps */
                for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                    String polyline = "";
                    polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                    List list = decodePoly(polyline);

                    /** Traversing all points */
                    for(int l=0;l <list.size();l++){
                        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                        hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                        path.add(hm);
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e){
    }

    return routes;
}

/**
 * Method to decode polyline points
 * Courtesy : jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
 * */
private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

    List poly = new ArrayList();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

}

Error occurs when I search something using places API and select the result I want.

Comment: Somewhere you have a JSONObject that you are trying to decode as a string, You expect something like `{"a":"b"}` however you are providing it  `{"a":{}}`

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at `onResponse` to see the actual result?